# Как сделать полупрозрачный border?

Tags: css

```
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 10px;
border-top-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
```

Сделал так но не работает.

Comment: Мне кажется придется делать прозрачную обвертку.

Comment: я это понимаю но хотелось бы по проще.

Comment: `border-top: 10px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3)` так не работает?

Comment: нет не работает

Comment: Можете попробовать сделать через box-shadow.

Comment: Хотя и ваш вариант работает ```border-top: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);```, можете показать, что у вас не так?

Comment: Может вы на самом деле утаиваете то, что под бордером у вас рисуется фон? Тогда сделайте в стилях `background-clip: padding-box;`.